# Excel online custom URL parameters

Tags: excel, sharepoint-online, excel-online

Im trying to create custom URL links that will enable a user to be navigated to a specific cell value on an Excel online sheet hosted in Sharepoint online.

In my quest to find the answer i have across this parameter that enables you to choose the starting cell location when the excel file opened.

&activeCell=%27Sheet1%27!A1

My concern is if the file is sorted and saved by the user the cell i referenced would contain a new value.

Is there anyway to use something similar to the above but specify the cell value
for example

&activeCell=%27Sheet1%27!A="Sales_Rep2"

Answer (score 0):

You could create a named range on the sheet and target that name with

```
Item=itemName
```

This is a bit more resilient than a cell address, even though not as ideal as a cell search or value.

From https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/embed-your-excel-workbook-on-your-web-page-or-blog-from-sharepoint-or-onedrive-for-business-7af74ce6-e8a0-48ac-ba3b-a1dd627b7773?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#_specifyadditionalparameters